# Store a Character Inside an Array

Tags: arrays, c, string, arraylist, char

I am trying to store a character inside an array, let's say the user inputs a set of numbers "100011000110" and for each 1 the output should be 'X' and for each 0 the output should be 'O'.

I think I got most of it figured out but somehow it's not working.

Any advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
# define BUFFER 100
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    
    char str[BUFFER], board[BUFFER], boardstr;
    int size,i;
    
    printf("Input numbers 1 and 0: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    size = strlen(str);
    
    for(i=0;i<size; i++)
        if(str[i]==0)
            board[i]= 'O';
        
        else(str[i]==1);
        
            board[i]='X';
            
    boardstr= strlen(board);
            
    printf("%c",boardstr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I.E input: 100110011000, output: XOOXXOOXXOOO

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details, like input and expected versus actual output.

Comment: "store a character inside an array" why? If your task is to map `0/1` to `O/X` then you do not need to store anything. Just read one character at a time and output one character accordingly.

Comment: As for the code, if you loop over a string whose length you got from `strlen` then you will never come across the null-terminator. So the condition `if(str[i]==0)` will *never* be true. Then `else(str[i]==1);` is invalid (and it's unlikely that you will get the integer `1` in the input, perhaps you meant the *character* `'1'`?). Also `boardstr` is not a character. There seems to be some problems with your basic C knowledge, perhaps you should spend some time to refresh it.

Comment: Hint: The user input will not be `0` but `'0'`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback, I started programming very recently and will refer back to the basics, thanks :)